# If the roots of equation $z^2 +\alpha z+\beta =0 $ lie on $|z|=1$ then :

Tags: complex-numbers

> If the roots of equation $z^2 +\alpha z+\beta =0 $ lie on $|z|=1$ then :
>
> (1) $2|\mbox{Im}(\alpha)|=1-|\beta|^2$
>
> (2) $2|\mbox{Im}(\alpha)|=|\beta|^2-1$
>
> (3) $\mbox{Im}(\alpha)=0$
>
> (4) $\text{None of these }$

**My work**. Let $z$ be one solution of the equation
$$z=-\left(\alpha +\frac{\beta}{z}\right)$$
Taking conjugate of whole equation .
$$\overline{z}=-\left(\overline{\alpha }+\frac{\overline{\beta}}{\overline{z}}\right)$$
$$z-\overline{z}=-\left(\alpha -\overline{\alpha} +\frac{\beta}{z}-\frac{\overline{\beta}}{\overline{z}}\right).$$
One further solving
$$\left|\frac{1-\overline{\beta}}{\overline{z}}+\frac{\beta-1}{z}\right|=2\mbox{Im}(\alpha)$$
$$\sqrt{2|\beta|^2-\beta^2- \overline{\beta}^2}=2|\mbox{Im}(\alpha)|$$

Is my approach and answer correct ? Is there any other way ?

Comment: Considering $(z-i)^2=z^2-2iz-1$ is enough to exclude 1), 2), 3).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint. Let $z_1$ and $z_2$ be the roots of equation $z^2 +\alpha z+\beta =0 $. Then
$$z^2 +\alpha z+\beta =(z-z_1)(z-z_2)=z^2-(z_1+z_2)z+z_1z_2$$
Hence if $z_1$ and $z_2$ lie on $|z|=1$ then $|\beta|=|z_1z_2|=1$.
It follows that each options (1), (2) and (3) implies that $\mbox{Im}(\alpha)=0$.

Now consider the counterexample $(z-i)(z-1)=z^2-(1+i)z+i$. Then $\alpha=-(1+i)$ and $\mbox{Im}(\alpha)=-1$.

Comment: But how to use $|\beta|=1$ .

Comment: @AakashKumar $|\beta|=1$ and (1),(2) and (3) imply that $|\mbox{Im}(\alpha)|=0$. But there are counterexamples...

Comment: @AakashKumar Any further doubt?

Comment: Thanks ,I have no further doubts .